# JQuery GET function only work first time when call on change() function

Tags: jquery, onchange, jquery-get

I've following method asscoiated a drown box

```
$('#cboUsuario').on('change',
            function cargarAccesos(){
                var username = $('#cboUsuario').val();
                $.get('listEmpresasAcceso', {usuario: username, accion: 'SELECT'}, function(responseJson) {
                    $('#tblAccesosEmpresa').empty();
                    $('#tblAccesosEmpresa').append('<tr><td></td><td>Empresa</td></tr>');
                    for(var i = 0; i < responseJson.length; i++){
                        $check = '<input id="id' + responseJson[i].id + '" type="checkbox" value="' + responseJson[i].id + '" onclick="insertarAcceso(this)">';
                        $empresa = responseJson[i].descripcion;
                        $row = $('<tr><td>' + $check + '</td><td>' + $empresa + '</td></tr>');
                        $('#tblAccesosEmpresa').append($row);
                        $('#id' + responseJson[i].id).prop('checked', responseJson[i].flagAcceso == "1" ? true : false);
                    }
                });
            }
        );
```

In GET function I call a servlet that load data from database.
This is drown box

```
<select id="cboUsuario" onchange="cargarAccesos()">
```

Suppose that these are the values on drown box:

```
<option value="1">Default Value</option>
<option value="2">Car</option>
<option value="3">Phone</option>
<option value="4">Computer</option>
```

When I select the Car option, change() function is invoked and GET function also is invoked. When I select the Phone options, change() function is invoked anew and also GET function. But when I select again the Car option, change() function is invoked, but don't GET function. GET function don't invoke to servlet and only return the old values ​​of the first time it was invoked.

Anybody can explain what's going on?

Comment: It's probably caching your previous request, try adding `cache: false,` to your `$.get` call.

Comment: There aren't messages. I've debugged on IE 8. Change function always is invoked, but not get() function. When I select again a option that it was selected before, get() function don't call a servlet class. I tested in Eclipse

Comment: Thanks for help  :D!. I try this `$.ajaxSetup ({cache: false });` and work fine. I don't know if you mean the same

Comment: I posted it as an answer for ya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is most likely caching your old request, try adding `cache: false,` to your $.get call.

```
$.ajaxSetup ({cache: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two triggers assigned, one from a jquery event and the other from standard javascript. either change your code to use jquery or standard javascript.

Do the following with no `onchange` trigger on html.

```
$('#cboUsuario').on('change',
        function (){
            var username = $('#cboUsuario').val();
            $.get('listEmpresasAcceso', {usuario: username, accion: 'SELECT'}, function(responseJson) {
                $('#tblAccesosEmpresa').empty();
                $('#tblAccesosEmpresa').append('<tr><td></td><td>Empresa</td></tr>');
                for(var i = 0; i < responseJson.length; i++){
                    $check = '<input id="id' + responseJson[i].id + '" type="checkbox" value="' + responseJson[i].id + '" onclick="insertarAcceso(this)">';
                    $empresa = responseJson[i].descripcion;
                    $row = $('<tr><td>' + $check + '</td><td>' + $empresa + '</td></tr>');
                    $('#tblAccesosEmpresa').append($row);
                    $('#id' + responseJson[i].id).prop('checked', responseJson[i].flagAcceso == "1" ? true : false);
                }
            });
        }
    );
```

or remove the event attachment with `on` and just have the function

```
        function cargarAccesos(){
            var username = $('#cboUsuario').val();
            $.get('listEmpresasAcceso', {usuario: username, accion: 'SELECT'}, function(responseJson) {
                $('#tblAccesosEmpresa').empty();
                $('#tblAccesosEmpresa').append('<tr><td></td><td>Empresa</td></tr>');
                for(var i = 0; i < responseJson.length; i++){
                    $check = '<input id="id' + responseJson[i].id + '" type="checkbox" value="' + responseJson[i].id + '" onclick="insertarAcceso(this)">';
                    $empresa = responseJson[i].descripcion;
                    $row = $('<tr><td>' + $check + '</td><td>' + $empresa + '</td></tr>');
                    $('#tblAccesosEmpresa').append($row);
                    $('#id' + responseJson[i].id).prop('checked', responseJson[i].flagAcceso == "1" ? true : false);
                }
            }
```